# Ubuntu 18.04 strange behaviour of date with --date option

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, date

I've found strange behaviour of `date` program in Ubuntu 18.04.

So, I consider `date` should work with `--date option` and correctly process +N minutes:

```
date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 +1 minutes" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

But, in Ubuntu 16.04 I will get:

```
2019-01-01 13:44:32
```

And in 18.04:

```
2019-01-01 12:44:32
```

The solution is add `+1 hours` as well, but, wait a minute, why I'm getting minus one hour when I do plus one minute?

Comment: No problem here. Did you set `TZ` in your shell? Test with `echo $TZ`. Also look at `timedatectl` output.

Comment: I also see 12:44:32 with timezone set to UTC, on RHEL 7. Something strange is going on here.

Comment: `echo $TZ` does not return anything, means it's not set.

`timedatectl` shows the next:

                      Local time: Tue 2019-02-05 09:42:12 GMT
                  Universal time: Tue 2019-02-05 09:42:12 UTC
                        RTC time: Tue 2019-02-05 09:42:12
                       Time zone: Europe/London (GMT, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no

Comment: I see it even with timezone set: one of my machines running 18.04 is a desktop so it is set to `America/New_York` instead of UTC. It says the result of the command in the question is `... 07:44:32` but it should really be `... 08:44:32`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that `date` is treating the `+1` part as the timezone, and **not** as an extra minute. The extra minute is coming only from the word `minutes` which is parsed as "add one minute" because it is unclear.

You can see this if you try the following commands:

- Your original command, which is interpreted as if it says "at time zone UTC +1".

  ```
  $ date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 +1 minutes" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  2019-01-01 12:44:32
  ```
- Change to `+2` and notice that the hour is reduced by one but the minute stays the same. This is interpreted as "at time zone UTC +2".

  ```
  $ date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 +2 minutes" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  2019-01-01 11:44:32
  ```
- Observe that just using `+1` (without `minutes`) gives the behavior of only changing the hour, not the minute.

  ```
  $ date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 +1" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  2019-01-01 12:43:32
  ```
- Observe that the word `minutes` is interpreted as adding a single minute.

  ```
  $ date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 minutes" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  2019-01-01 13:44:32
  ```

---

### Here is some of the relevant documentation:

- From the `info date` command output, section `21.1.6 Options for ‘date’`:

  > ```
  > ... For example, ‘--date="2004-02-27 14:19:13.489392193 +0530"’
  > specifies the instant of time that is 489,392,193 nanoseconds after
  > February 27, 2004 at 2:19:13 PM in a time zone that is 5 hours and
  > 30 minutes east of UTC. ...
  > ```

  Note the use of `+530` to describe the time zone.
- From the `info date` command output, section `28.7 Relative items in date strings`:

  > ```
  > ... The unit of time may be preceded by a multiplier, given as an
  > optionally signed number.  Unsigned numbers are taken as positively
  > signed.  No number at all implies 1 for a multiplier.  Following a
  > relative item by the string ‘ago’ is equivalent to preceding the unit by
  > a multiplier with value -1. ...
  > ```

  Note the text: "No number at all implies 1 for a multiplier".

---

### So how can you get around this?

One option is to reverse the order of the string elements:

```
$ date --date "+1 minutes 2019-01-01 13:43:32" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-01-01 13:44:32
```

Another option (the option I'd prefer) is to explicitly specify the time zone:

```
$ date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 UTC +1 minutes" "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
2019-01-01 13:44:32
```

(Note that you can also use `+0` or `Z` as alternatives to `UTC` in the string above.)

---

Also note that if you are using `date` version 8.26 or newer (as Ubuntu 18.04 is; 16.04 is using 8.25), you can add the `--debug` flag for `date` to tell you how it parsed the input text:

```
$ date --date "2019-01-01 13:43:32 +1 minutes" --debug "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2019-01-01
date: parsed time part: 13:43:32 UTC+01
date: parsed relative part: +1 minutes
date: input timezone: parsed date/time string (+01)
date: using specified time as starting value: '13:43:32'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 13:43:32 TZ=+01'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 13:43:32 TZ=+01' = 1546346612 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+0 hours, +1 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1546346672 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1546346672.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 12:44:32 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 12:44:32 (UTC+00)
2019-01-01 12:44:32
```

vs.

```
$ date --date "+1 minutes 2019-01-01 13:43:32" --debug "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
date: parsed relative part: +1 minutes
date: parsed date part: (Y-M-D) 2019-01-01
date: parsed time part: 13:43:32
date: input timezone: system default
date: using specified time as starting value: '13:43:32'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 13:43:32'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 13:43:32' = 1546350212 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+0 hours, +1 minutes, +0 seconds, +0 ns),
date:     new time = 1546350272 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: system default
date: final: 1546350272.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 13:44:32 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2019-01-01 13:44:32 (UTC+00)
2019-01-01 13:44:32
```

---

Final note: I have no idea why you get a different output on 16.04. On my 16.04 machines I get the same result as my 18.04 machines. I also looked through the git history of GNU coreutils, and I don't see any commits that would have obviously caused such a change.

Comment: Thanks for such wide answer! Based on your answer, I think that 16.04 gives me different value, because it has different time zone (it has UTC +2)